# How do I add numerical values of a JSON array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, object

I am trying to add these integer values from this Array object to get the sum and in turn the average.

```
Input: [
        {"string": "John", "integer": 7},
        {"string": "Margot", "integer": 8},
        {"string": "Jules", "integer": 4},
        {"string": "Marco", "integer": 19}
       ]

Output: 9.5
```

I have been able to do this function, however, I am not able to add the values from the integer into a sum variable and divide by the objectName.length. My sample code is beneath, I want to understand why it is not working?

```
function my_average_mark(student_grades) {
    sum = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < student_grades.length; i++){
        // console.log(student_grades[i].integer);
        sum += student_grades[i].integer;
        console.log(sum);
        
    }
    
};


all_grades = [
        {"string": "John", "integer": 7},
        {"string": "Margot", "integer": 8},
        {"string": "Jules", "integer": 4},
        {"string": "Marco", "integer": 19}
       ]
console.log(my_average_mark(all_grades));
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object" (or a _"JSON array object"_)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/) - `Input` and `all_grades` are arrays of objects...

Comment: Note you arent returning anything from your function, so the last log won't show anything

Comment: As @Nick already mentioned why it's not working the one line solution is something like this `console.log(Input.reduce((n, {integer}) => n + integer, 0)/Input.length)`

Comment: @PatrickEvans actually my last log printed out something. but it was adding up values for my integer values. Nick suggestion helped out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost right, you just need to `return` the sum divided by the length:

```js
function my_average_mark(student_grades) {
  let sum = 0;
  let len = student_grades.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sum += student_grades[i].integer;
  }
  return Math.round(sum * 10 / len) / 10;
};


all_grades = [
        {"string": "John", "integer": 7},
        {"string": "Margot", "integer": 8},
        {"string": "Jules", "integer": 4},
        {"string": "Marco", "integer": 19}
       ]
console.log(my_average_mark(all_grades));
```

Note you should always declare your variables using `var`, `let` or `const`.

Comment: @AsanteMichael I modified your edit to use `Math.round` to round to 1 decimal place instead; using `toFixed` would mean that the function would return a string instead of a number.

Answer (score 2):

```
function my_average_mark(student_grades) {
    sum = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < student_grades.length; i++){
        sum += student_grades[i].integer;        
    }
    return sum / student_grades.length;
};
```

consider using array functions like map and reduce

```
function my_average_mark(student_grades) {
    sum = student_grades.map(p => p.integer).reduce((a,b) => a+b, 0)
    return sum / student_grades.length;
};
```